# No GPS tags on iPhone photos

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, gps

iPhone 7 plus with latest iOS.  To the best of my knowledge, I have never disabled location services for Camera or Compass.  I’ve taken many photos and most have GPS tags embedded.  But today, I took 22 images of gravestones in a cemetery on a partly cloudy day with very few trees, and none of them have GPS tags.  At one point, I looked at my compass app, which also shows lat/long and it was showing believable values.  Checked the settings, and location services is still enabled for both apps.

**What would make an iPhone intermittently NOT add location data to photos?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's not iPhone's fault.  When you copy one or more photos from Photos.app to a Finder window by dragging, the GPS data is discarded.

To keep the GPS data (and who knows what else¹), you have to use the menu bar, File→Export→Export unmodified original for xxx items.

¹I think it was a stupid design decision.  Your opinion may vary.

Comment: Your question doesn‘t mention a Mac at all, made it a bid hard for others to answer this.

Comment: That's correct.  It doesn't mention Mac because the photos were taken on iPhone.  The _answer_ refers to Mac because when first asked, I had no way of knowing that the Mac had done the damage.

Comment: The fact that you looked at the photos on the Mac might have been useful in analysing the issue. But glad that you found the cause.